# Difference between std::vector and std::array

Tags: c++

I am doing the codecademy c++ course and just went over vectors and arrays. From what I understand, the only difference between the two is that you can change the size of a vector, but cannot change the size of an array. Are there any other differences that I am missing that would make them more useful in the future?

Comment: *the only difference between the two is that you can change the size of a vector,*  -- Vectors do not decay to pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie neither does `std::array`. But both containers do have a `data()` method for getting such a pointer

Comment: I was assuming the author was referring to regular arrays, not std::array.

Answer (score 2):

A major difference is that `std::vector` allocates memory, i.e. it uses the heap for storage. An array (`std::array` or a built-in one) does not.

Allocating memory is a major difference because it is a very expensive operation relative to many others (when using the default allocator).